# Generating rss.xml for Angular 8 app locally works fine, but not on prod

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, google-cloud-platform, rss

I am trying to generate a `rss.xml` file for my angular 8 app with ssr + firebase + gcp inside the domain.

I've created a `RssComponent` which can be reached at `/rss` route. There i call `getNews()` method and receive an array of objects. Then I make a http request to `/api/rss` and in `server.ts` i handle that request:

```
app.post('/api/rss', (req, res) => {
  const data = req.body.data;
  const feedOptions = // defining options here
  const feed = new RSS(feedOptions);
  data.forEach((item) => {
    feed.item({
      title:  item.headingUa,
      description: item.data[0].dataUa,
      url: item.rssLink,
      guid: item.id,
      date: item.utcDate,
      enclosure: {url: item.mainImg.url.toString().replace('&', '&amp;'), type: 'image/jpeg'}
    });
  });
  const xml = feed.xml({indent: true});
  fs.chmod('dist/browser/rss.xml', 0o600, () => {
    fs.writeFile('dist/browser/rss.xml', xml, 'utf8', function() {
        res.status(200).end();
    });
  });
});
```

And finally on response i'm opening the recently generated `rss.xml` file in `RssComponent`. Locally everything is working fine but on Google Cloud Platform it's not generating a file.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [the Cloud Functions docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system):

> The only writeable part of the filesystem is the `/tmp` directory

Try changing the path to the file to the `/tmp` directory.

Nevertheless, using local files in a serverless environment is a **really bad idea**. You should assume the instance handling the following request will not be the same as the previous one.

The best way to handle this would be to avoid writing local files and instead storing the generated file in [GCP Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage) or [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/products/storage), and then retrieving it from there when needed.

This will ensure your functions are idempotent, and also will comply with [the best practices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/tips).